# How to manually install java libs and keep /tmp as noexec?

Tags: java, android, linux

I am trying to run android sdk on a box that needs to have `noexec` on `/tmp`.

I could point java tmp to be another place where i can exec, but that would defeat the purpose of the police that requires `noexec` in tmp. So i do not want to do that just yet.

I wanted to properly install the libs that sdk requires but my java is rusty.

When I try to run it, I get:

```
$ Android/Sdk/tools/android 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3550 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:403)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:391)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:151)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:117)
```

My first try to work around that was:

```
$ sudo aptitude install libswt-gtk-3-java...
Selecting previously unselected package libswt-gtk-3-jni.
(Reading database ... 199270 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libswt-gtk-3-jni_3.8.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libswt-gtk-3-jni (3.8.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libswt-gtk-3-java.
Preparing to unpack .../libswt-gtk-3-java_3.8.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libswt-gtk-3-java (3.8.2-3) ...
Setting up libswt-gtk-3-jni (3.8.2-3) ...
Setting up libswt-gtk-3-java (3.8.2-3) ...
```

But I still get the same error. Does that means that the program is not looking for default libs but purposely trying to use something it unpacks on /tmp? Or will java unpack a jar always in /tmp, and try to run it from there, and there is nothing I can do?

EDIT:
To clear that the `noexec` is the cause. If I run the application with `-Djava.io.tmpdir=Android/tmp`, then everything works. And I have the following content in the new tmp dir:

```
Android/tmp/
└── swtlib-64
    ├── libswt-gtk-3550.so
    └── libswt-pi-gtk-3550.so
```

Edit 2:

```
$ ANDROID_SWT=/usr/lib/java/
$ ls $ANDROID_SWT/
    swt-gtk-3.8.2.jar
$ Android/Sdk/tools/android 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3550 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
...same...
```

Comment: What gave you the idea of `/tmp` being involved?

Comment: @Siguza that is the reason of that error. if i trace it that is where it got me. i can successfully work around that error by removing `noexec` or setting `java.io.tmpdir=/home/me/tmp`

Comment: This was here before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344903/problem-launching-android-avm-sdk-gui-using-the-tools-android-executable-in-the, albeit the actual reason why the Android SDK copies the SWT libraries to `/tmp` is still a mistery.

Comment: @dhke right, that was asking the cause and work around (i mention two solutions on the question itself, the last one being almost the same as the accepted answer there). this question is not the same. i picked that application just as an example to a bigger issue.

Comment: Does setting `ANDROID_SWT=/usr/lib` (or wherever the system `libswt` is located) help? The *extract lib from jar to filesystem* is an [SWT feature](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20PI/common_j2se/org/eclipse/swt/internal/Library.java#n321), but usually the library ends up in the user's home. Also note the comment on line 302, which leaves me confused, because where is tmp?

Comment: @dhke `ls $ANDROID_SWT/` shows `swt-gtk-3.8.2.jar` right in the dir.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you change the android sdk tools folder (in /opt) to be writable by you using `chown`, then the unpacking will happen within the sdk folder.  You could do this by creating an 'androidsdk' group.

Comment: the SDK dir is already writable. Still have no idea why on earth java/the application tries to unpack libs in tmp instead of using the exact same versions readily available on the system...