# I am getting a no space left on device error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools, android-virtual-device

I tried installing a tablet as a virtual device and after installing it , It does not even show and my gradle stopped syncing citing no space on device...

Also I could not get the gradle vm settings to increase the memory using the option -Xmx512m

I could not delete the virtual device as it does not show any as intsalled , i cannot add as it shows no image available and the standalone sdk manager also does not open saying lack of memory...

I have a lot of disk and RAM free  , and am at a loss...

I tried invalidating cache and restarting , that didnt help either...
Any help will be appreciated...

OS : Solus
Android Studio Version : 2.2

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, you have a physical device. If so, you need to install the tablet as ADB device (using the default Android driver or the ADB driver from the manufacturer).

Comment: no , a virtual device

Comment: I dont have a physical device and hence i tried to install a virtual one

Comment: You definitely have messed up something with the gradle options. You don't have to put any arguments anywhere, when creating virtual device in Android Studio (everything there is done through the GUI). So first fix that the SDK manager is not opening; if you have backup of the files, you've changed, bring them back.

Comment: No , when this issue occurred , I checked one of the solutions was to add that option...and i removed it when it didn't work...so its the same old gradle files...

Comment: Can you open the "SDK Manager.exe" from the folder where the Android SDK is installed.

Comment: I dont have that file...its linux...

Comment: Ok, try this - http://askubuntu.com/a/407600

Comment: read "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3550 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file

Comment: This is the error I'm getting....It didnt open even from the directory...

Comment: You have messed up some environmental variables; maybe you have added java args. Look closer this problem and the rest will come to resolvement. Maybe the following will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344903/problem-launching-android-avm-sdk-gui-using-the-tools-android-executable-in-the . Also edit your question and add the error text for someone to help you.

Comment: Thanks for all your help , ill try it out and let you know...

Answer (score 21):

Clearing the temporary folder worked for me...

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Comment: That potentially erases lock files, PID files, socket files and so on.

Comment: Not sure how erase temp can make damages but it workd for me.

Comment: No idea why, but this helped! Don't know why it needed `/tmp`....

Answer (score 7):

You can increase available space in tmp by doing remount instead of "rm -rf" :

```
mount -o remount,size=8G,noatime /tmp
```

Comment: Looks a nice idea to avoid it happen again.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me during Detox testing a React-Native android project.

All you have to do is increase VM heap size. mine initialized to 15mb, not very much.

Trying 512mb got rid of this error and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with a real device, and I just switched the USB connection type to something else (like USB tethering) temporarily and then immediately switched back to "Transferring files" and it worked (I could install the app file).

Answer (score -1):

I recently faced this problem I guess I have an answer.
Step 1 : Close the emulator which is currently running and in which you want to see your results.
Step 2 : Go to the AVD Manager in Android Studio which is a phone like icon and in there you will have your virtual machines displayed.
Step 3 : Select the down arrow symbol in the right most corner of your virtual machine and click wipe data.

This way all the data is wiped off and you can open your virtual machine again

Hope this works for you ! :)